# Heap corruption error in Visual Studio while freeing dynamic memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dynamic-arrays

I am having an issue with a function that concatenates a number to the end of a char array. I honestly can't see the issue:

```
void x(int num, char* originalArray) {

    char* concat_str = new char[1];
    sprintf(concat_str, "%d", num);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        originalArray[i + 10] = concat_str[i];

    delete [] concat_str;
   }
```

The error message is:

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#147) at 0x01204CA0. CRT detected that the application wrote to the memory after the end of heap buffer.

Any ideas? I'm a beginning programmer, but I've done this same kind of thing many times and never had this issue. Thanks.

Comment: **char* concat_str = new char[1];** You do realize a cstring of size 1 can contain only the null terminating character. Any digits of a number will be too many.

Comment: *but I've done this same kind of thing many times and never had this issue.*  -- You've stomped on memory many times and not had an issue??  Maybe you should review your old code, since doing what you're doing in the post is undefined behavior.

Comment: Why even bother with new and delete there?  Just declare a buffer on the stack, such as `concat_str[32];`.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string`? Especially if you're a beginner.

Comment: Or if you want to be really paranoid:  `concat_str[ (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT+2-1)/3 +2]` (that array might be too large, but it *cannot* be too small).  Edit: D'oh.  +1 for a minus sign, **+1 for a nul-terminator**!

Comment: @DanKorn Because I need the array to be dynamically sized, as each time this function is called with a different value which can't be const

Comment: Why the conversion (with adding space for the null terminator) is 2 bytes always supporting num from 0 to 9? A fixed char array would be more efficient than dynamically allocating.

Comment: You say, "Because I need the array to be dynamically sized."  What array?  The originalArray parameter?  Okay, but then why do you need to "new" the local variable concat_str ?  Don't be "heap happy."  Just declare concat_str as a fixed-size array on the stack for the sprintf call.

Comment: @DanKorn creating concat_str on the stack is what I originally had planned, but could not find a generalized way to size it like it needed to be sized. I am getting the expected results with the dynamic allocation.

Comment: Okay, if it's working, that's great, but I don't see how 32 bytes could ever be insufficient for any integer that you're sprintf'ing with the %d format specifier.  And the stack allocation will almost always be faster than going to the heap.  But it's your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`concat_str` needs to be large enough to hold the number of digits in `num` plus a null terminator.  Since it size is one you only have enough room for the null terminator.  Trying to add anything else is undefined behavior as it accesses memory you do not own and causing the heap corruption.

Comment: Ah the null terminator. I made the size of the array one more than it should be, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @revolution9540 Why only one more?  There is no need to be on a knife's edge.  Ensure that you have enough space by making the array larger than what you expect.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm just trying to be as efficient as possible I guess? If I know exactly what is going to be stored in the array, why would it be a good idea to make it larger than needed?

Comment: @revolution9540 What is the actual purpose of the code you posted? ie why are you doing this.  I would not think dynamic allocations are even needed here with this example code.

Comment: Currently your program will break if the integer is greater than 9. Maybe you should have a conditional to verify that the number is between 0 and 9. Or just add more space..

Comment: @revolution9540 If I had a dollar for every time a programmer tried to micromanage how large to make their array to fit the output, and then have their program crash due to an out-of-bounds access, I would be a rich man.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the only reason I am making a dynamic allocation is because if I did char concat_str[size], size would have to be constant, and since size is used in other places in the code I did not post, I cannot make it constant. Therefore I used dynamic allocation to bypass requirement that array size be constant, and I am getting the expected results. It's my mistake for specifying "1" in the above code. The allocation size is actually a non-const variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating one byte for concat_str, and sprintf'ing something that requires more space than that.

Comment: It's also not clear whether you're overrunning whatever originalArray buffer is passed in.  There should be some kind of check for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that your API is a C api. If you want a dynamic array in C++, use `std::vector<char>`.

But, assuming you need to stick to the C API, there's no way to guarantee that your `originalArray` is large enough to hold the result. Furthermore, the temporary buffer is unnecessary.

You should modify the API and the implementation as follows:

1. Take the size of the destination, to guarantee that it doesn't write past its end.
2. Write the string in place in the destination buffer. Putting it into a temporary buffer and then copying to the destination is a waste of time.
3. Use `snprintf`, not `sprintf`. The latter is not safe: you can't guarantee it won't write past the end of your buffer.
4. You should assert the precondition that the offset is at least smaller than the destination size.

   If the precondition holds, the destination will be always properly zero-terminated, although the text representation of `num` might not fit in it.
5. You can return the length of the destination that is necessary for the value to fit.

Thus:

```
size_t fun(int num, char * dest, size_t dest_size) {
  const size_t offset = 10;
  assert(dest_size > offset);
  return offset + snprintf(dest + offset, dest_size - offset, "%d", num);
}
```